# Image looks blur after resizing to 413*531 pixels in android

Tags: android

In my app I am capturing image then applying crop in the second activity,then resizing that captured image and sending it to the server.The saved image looks blur.How to save the image with good quality after resizing.Here is my code:

```
 PassImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bitmap photo = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("image");
                resultIv.setImageBitmap(photo);
                // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
                Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);
                // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
                File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
                int x = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 413, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                int y = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 531, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                cropView.of(Uri.fromFile(finalFile)).withAspect(x, y).initialize(Image.this);
            }
        });

           @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                //Converting Bitmap to String
                String image = getStringImage(croppedBitmap);         
                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                //Adding parameters
                params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);        
                return params;
            }

    //resize image
    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int width = 413;
        int height = 531;
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, false);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
```

Comment: Try using external libraries such as Picasso or glide for getting compressed bitmap. And sent that bitmap image to server may solve your issue.

Comment: As a first thing try probably `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);` (filtering ON). BTW, I'm too lazy to try it out, what is result of `(int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 413, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());`? And as you enter those only as aspect ration, you can simply do `withAspect(413, 531)` instead. I would understand the complex transformation in case physical pixel size (it's aspect ratio) would be adjusted, but it's not, both x and y are treated in same way. And if you would adjust it per dimension, it would later fool the hardcoded scale.

Comment: Anyway, to debug the issue, keep storing on sdcard Image data (in PNG form, so it's lossless exact copy) in each step of processing (after capture, after crop, after scale), to see how the quality of pixel data evolves after each step.

Comment: @ Nivedh:I tried as u said.But while resizing again it is blur only.

Comment: @ Ped7g I used withAspect(413, 531) now.But how can I save without blur. I tried with Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true); But no use.

Comment: But where is the blur coming from, from which step? Did you save PNG images for every step to see, what is the input quality? If you have already blurred image at the beginning, you will not get sharper one by cutting it and scaling (actually scaling it down will somewhat fix the blur, but it's not adding fidelity, ie information bits, it's just presenting the original amount of information on smaller area, thus giving sense of higher fidelity). How do you even check the server image, don't you have some bug on server side showing the good image in blurred way?

Comment: BTW, don't put space between @ and nick, it will not notify the user about your comment. You should write "@Amshu" without space to get the notifications (extra notif, the author of question/answer gets notified of each comment).

Answer (score 0):

Use following method to compress the image :

```
public String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
        String imageBase64String;

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        imageBase64String = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

        return imageBase64String;
    }
```

To decompile :

```
 private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 512;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Where I should use resize of image if I use this?I Want to save the image 413*531 pixels in server.

Comment: You get an image path after cropping image, decode that path to bitmap and use this compression method before sending it to server.

Comment: In my code also am using compression method.If I dont resize then I am not getting the desired out put.So I have used   Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, false);  iside getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) method.

Comment: See my recent edit. Don't use hard code static values to compress. Instead scale the image properly.

Comment: Where I have to use decodeFile() method. and if I use  REQUIRED_SIZE = 512; what will the height and width of image??

Comment: I mentioned this before also, after cropping the image and at least hit and try to get the results, then customize the size if required.